# How to fix 'Data has already been sent to output, unable to output PDF file' in MPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

I tried to use MPDF library for generating PDF.

```
try {
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
        // Other code
        $mpdf->Output("1.pdf", 'D');
    } catch (\Mpdf\MpdfException $e) { // Note: safer fully qualified exception name used for catch
        // Process the exception, log, print etc.
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

And I get this error message.

> Data has already been sent to output, unable to output PDF file

I used ob_end_clean() but not working.
I used all answers in this question but nothing works for me.
TCPDF & mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCPDF & mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146967/tcpdf-mpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-to-browser-cant-send-pdf)

Comment: I used all answers in that problem but not working.
If you have other solution, please let me know

Comment: I already used that solution but not working for me

Comment: can u show the full code

Comment: That's all.
I integrated this into my project for generating PDF.
And I just wanted to export simple "Hello World!" but not working.

Comment: Thats because there's an output somewhere in your code hence I want you to show the full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191525/discussion-between-anton-egorovich-and-masivuye-cokile).

Comment: You moste likely have some output in the code above that. Be aware that if your starting ` <?php` has a whitespace in front of it, that will be sent to the browser and seen as output.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same error.

> Data has already been sent to output, unable to output PDF file

This means before creating a PDF with mPDF some data is stored in the buffer which is sent to the browser. Therefore it is unable to create PDF.

To rectify this, add this below php built-in function at the first line of your page were you are preparing data for pdf.

```
ob_start();
```

And add this below php built-in function before mPDF code (before where you are calling mpdf)

```
ob_end_flush();

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

This will clear the buffer output before processing mPDF.

Make sure if you use any functions to keep them on the same page, don't include a functions page where you have kept your all functions.

Read more about [PHP Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and the correct solution for it is the following.
if when you type *<?php* in your script as the very first word, **make sure there are no space characters or any characters** before *<?php* whatsoever. This also happens with anything else giving the error *Data has already been sent to output*. Space characters like space and TAB don't appear to you and it will definitely deceive you.

This won't appear easily to anyone.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it helped to insert `<?php` instead of `<?`.

Comment: There's no difference between `<?php` and `<?`